# correctness of in-place convolution filter?

Tags: javascript

I have a simple box blur function that takes an `ImageData` object, returning it when done. However, I have just realised that this implementation may be incorrect because the `ImageData` object is edited in place and convolution filters depend on surrounding pixels. Should I be reading from the original `ImageData` and writing to a new one so that each pixel doesn't depend on already-changed surrounding pixels? If so, I'll have to rework my web worker manager to supply a new `ImageData` for the convolution functions to write to.

```
expressive.boxBlur = function(data, options) {
    var w = data.width, h = data.height, dataReal = data.data;
    for (var i = 0; i < w; i++)
        for (var j = 0; j < h; j++)
            for (var k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
                var total = 0, values = 0, temp = 0;
                if (!(i == 0 && j == 0)) {
                    temp = dataReal[4 * w * (j - 1) + 4 * (i - 1) + k];
                    if (temp !== undefined) values++, total += temp;
                }
                if (!(i == w - 1 && j == 0)) {
                    temp = dataReal[4 * w * (j - 1) + 4 * (i + 1) + k];
                    if (temp !== undefined) values++, total += temp;
                }
                if (!(i == 0 && j == h - 1)) {
                    temp = dataReal[4 * w * (j + 1) + 4 * (i - 1) + k];
                    if (temp !== undefined) values++, total += temp;
                }
                if (!(i == w - 1 && j == h - 1)) {
                    temp = dataReal[4 * w * (j + 1) + 4 * (i + 1) + k];
                    if (temp !== undefined) values++, total += temp;
                }
                if (!(j == 0)) {
                    temp = dataReal[4 * w * (j - 1) + 4 * (i + 0) + k];
                    if (temp !== undefined) values++, total += temp;
                }
                if (!(j == h - 1)) {
                    temp = dataReal[4 * w * (j + 1) + 4 * (i + 0) + k];
                    if (temp !== undefined) values++, total += temp;
                }
                if (!(i == 0)) {
                    temp = dataReal[4 * w * (j + 0) + 4 * (i - 1) + k];
                    if (temp !== undefined) values++, total += temp;
                }
                if (!(i == w - 1)) {
                    temp = dataReal[4 * w * (j + 0) + 4 * (i + 1) + k];
                    if (temp !== undefined) values++, total += temp;
                }
                values++, total += dataReal[4 * w * j + 4 * i + k];
                total /= values;
                dataReal[4 * w * j + 4 * i + k] = total;
            }
    return data;
};
```

Comment: Just FYI, CamanJS (http://camanjs.com/) provides arch for this kind of stuff. Depending on your case you might be able to reuse that somehow.

Comment: So it looks like you didn't chose to implement [those suggestions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314037/any-more-optimisation-i-can-do-for-this-function) ;-)

Comment: Ah, I haven't had the time to do any work on this library since the day of that question unfortunately. After I fix up the workers and `ImageData` passing problems, I'll replace this with a generic convolution function that takes in a convolution matrix. And I'll certainly take into account the advice from that question where applicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, you need a separate image to put the convoluted result in. Unless the impuls response is a scaled dirac function. (i.e. it has only 1 point in the center)

However, you could do with a cache for only a few scanlines, saving a lot of memory.